# Webhooks for box API are not working

Tags: box-api

Has anyone used webhooks to create real time event notification with box.com? I tried configuring it but seems like it is not working. More specifically, the endpoint I would like box to invoke on create and upload events simply doesn't seem to be getting called. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

-Anil

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit a support ticket to get your webhooks enabled.  Make sure you specify your application name, and give a brief explanation of what your webhook does.

Once you do that, Box usually is able to turn on your webhook within a day.

Comment: Hi, I worked with box support to enable it. Unfortunately, that still isn't working. Here is what I am noticing - I have 2 accounts. The first one where I created my app. Then I went into second account and added the app as per your instruction below. When I am in second account and upload a file, I expect the configured event endpoint to be called. Is that right expectation? Because I am not seeing it is getting called. Any help would be quite appreciated